# How to create a map in terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I'm confused on how to get this working, I have a sub-domian (module.foo.dev) and alternate domain name as *.foo.dev but it has to use the same zone_id as my root_domain.

I'm trying to use a local map something like

```
all_domains = {
  ["module.foo.dev","*.foo.dev"] = "foo.dev"
  ["bar.com"] = "bar.com"
}
```

My variables are as follows
primary_domain = "module.foo.dev"
sub_alternate_domain = ["*.foo.dev","bar.com"]

Eventually would be using that locals value in the below module
module:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {

  count      = var.validation_method == "DNS" ? local.all_domains : 0
  name       = aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type       = aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  zone_id    = data.aws_route53_zone.selected[count.index].zone_id
  ttl        = "300"
  records    = [aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value]

}
```

Can someone pls help me with this solution..

Comment: You can find the syntax for map type initialization in the documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/map.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard the map function is deprecated.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea That link had both the old function and current initialization syntax for maps.

Comment: @MattSchuchard no debate there, just clarifying that readers should not see it as an invitation to use the **map** function. Interestingly, the TF12 map syntax example there is better than the one in the expression language doc. Strange world.

Answer (score 3):

In Terraform a map can only have strings as keys (unquoted keys are still strings), so you need to swap your keys and values:

```
locals{
  all_domains = {
    "foo.dev" = ["module.foo.dev","*.foo.dev"]
    "bar.com" = ["bar.com"]
  }
}
```

Also, as above, your local variables need to be declared and assigned in a locals block.

The **count** argument on resources expects a whole non-negative number (0 or more) and will not accept a map as a value. You'll need to use for_each instead:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {

  for_each      = var.validation_method == "DNS" ? local.all_domains : {}
  name       = aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name
  type       = aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type
  zone_id    = data.aws_route53_zone.selected[count.index].zone_id
  ttl        = "300"
  records    = [aws_acm_certificate.certificate.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value]

}
```

The [map type in the Expression Language doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#map) provides some minimal additional guidance.

Comment: @user6826691 your question was "How to create a map in terraform". Is there something I missed in answering that? It seems like you are asking a separate question now and you should mark this correct, then ask the followup question separately.